# Using session to output values from POST

Tags: php, session

I have set this code, what i would like to do is to output the data from $_POST[$field] using session so that it will be saved,because i also have another page that i want to save the name and the family name from POST after successful registration.

```
 <body>
    <?php

       if (isset($_POST["vorname"]) && isset($_POST["nachname"]) && isset($_POST["geburtstag"])&&    
           isset($_POST["email"])   && isset($_POST["telefon"])  && isset($_POST["adresse"]))

    $formular = array('vorname','nachname','geburtstag','email','telefon','adresse');

                if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {                  
                 foreach($formular as $field) {  
                 $_SESSION['login'][$field]=$_POST[$field];              
                   print_r($_SESSION['login'][$_POST[$field]] . '<br><br>');
                    }
                   }

    ?>     
      <div class="div">
         <form action="login.php" method="post">
         <div>Vorname   </div><input type="text"  name="vorname"   required>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $vornameErr;?></span>
         <div>Nachname  </div><input type="text"  name="nachname"  required>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $nachnameErr;?></span>
         <div>Geburtstag</div><input type="text" name="geburtstag" required>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $geburtstagErr;?></span>
         <div>Email     </div><input type="Email" name="email"     required>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
         <div>Telefon   </div><input type="text"  name="telefon"   required>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $telefonErr;?></span>
         <div>Adresse   </div><input type="text"  name="adresse"   required>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $adresseErr;?></span><br>
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form> 
      </div>
      <br>
      <a href="kunden.php">kunden</a>

    </body>
    </html>
And this is the other page that i want to save the name and family name in to it using session

    <?php
       $a=array(
              array('mousa','123'),             
              array('',''));
              if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))     
              if(in_array(array($_POST["name"],$_POST["password"]),$a)){               
                header('Location:login.php');
                }

              if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
                 print_r($_SESSION['login'][$_POST["vorname"]]); 

               }


   ?>
```

Comment: Did you use session_start anywhere? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: what is your problem? did u start session ?

Comment: yes i did in both pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving in session using

```
$_SESSION['login'][$field]
```

but printing

```
$_SESSION['login'][$_POST[$field]]
```

and you have concatenated the data with `'<br><br>'` when printing

Change:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {                  
             foreach($formular as $field) {  
             $_SESSION['login'][$field]=$_POST[$field];              
               print_r($_SESSION['login'][$_POST[$field]] . '<br><br>');
                }
               }
```

to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {                  
             foreach($formular as $field) {  
             $_SESSION['login'][$field]=$_POST[$field];              
               print_r($_SESSION['login'][$field]) . '<br><br>';
                }
               }
```

Comment: i also would like to save the name and family name from POST in the other page that  i have.
and to keep adding names when ever i write in POST.
i mean that the data should be added not to replace the old name and famile name

Comment: Make the session variable an array: $_SESSION["login"] = array(); then for each new entry push new objects on the array: $_SESSION["login"][] = $userData; and set the $userData[$field] = $_POST[...